# Objective-C , Avoid negative float value to be displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have the following code :

```
float temp;
temp = 2.0f;
- (IBAction)MinusTouched:(id)sender {
    if (temp>0.0) {
        temp=temp-0.1f;
        [TempValue setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",temp]];
    }
}
```

When i perform action by clicking on the button , temp value decreases. But it prints -0.0 after 0.1 , how can i trim the negative sign ?
I mean i want an absolute float value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making float negative values in positive use `fabs`

```
[TempValue setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",fabs(temp)]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method

```
fabs(temp)
```

Comment: As a note on terminology, `fabs` is a function, not a method. "Method" is strictly a term for functions bound to classes.